# 404 on all assets with Latest odoo 13 image

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-13

I created an instance of the latest official odoo image with postgres behind and started using it. After recreation of the container due to odoo config changes I got a 404 on all assets after the recreation of the odoo container, which leads to an empty white page.

So at the moment I can't use odoo anymore.

Any ideas?

This is the output of the odoo container. I get a few of similar cache related exceptions:

```
2020-08-07 07:58:02,193 1 INFO XXXX 
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /var/lib/odoo/filestore/XXXXXX/02/02141d5e40545807c7f22145c21af626c109ddfb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 745, in get
value = self._data[field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 286

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 996, in 
__get__
value = env.cache.get(record, self)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 751, in get
raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.attachment(286,).datas', None)
```

Comment: What are first lines from log? Sometimes it says if it cant connect to some things.

Comment: Thanks for caring. I edit my question. Hope it helps

Comment: how did you configured ``/var/lib/odoo/filestore`` it has to be accessible and writable. Also its contents must be preserved as long with database. You can delete or clear it only when you start new database. Also on backup and restore its contents have to backuped and restored

Comment: I use the official docker images for odoo and postgres, so I exptected that this would be working naturally. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know exactly: https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/b4c45baf1f0579c654129ac9efe99a929569dab6/13.0/Dockerfile#L69
I am using docker-compose and with that, I am mounting external volume for the filestore.

Comment: ok, i should have used docker-composed from the beginning. Lessons learned. Now I do not get any problems after killing containers. Thx